# How can you rewrite an internal link access from external hostname?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What if I have some internal links on my xampp web server that need to get accessed by external (requests from the internet)?

Lets say  http://mylocalsite.local/login/    is a link on the site.

if I click on this link  from  http://externalwebsiteaddress.com, which should redirect to my webserver. Can the internal link (mylocalsite) be rewritten to http://externalwebsiteaddress.com/login ? Because currently external requests give a "Cannot access this page error" because its internal.

I don't want the internal link to redirect to the external link when accessed from within the network.

Basically if the links are internal , then find a way to service the request from external website successfully, without having to physically change the link on the server.

in other words

If the user is accessing from an external internet link, then find a way to redirect to proper folder using external link so it can be resolved properly.
EX: All links start with http://externalwebsiteaddress/wherever

If user is accessing from internal (inside the network) , then use the local links.
EX: All links start with  http://internaladdress/wherever

Would this be a mod_rewrite?  I am confusing myself way to much.

Comment: Maybe you can try something with [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: See also [Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html)

Comment: You need to use conditions based on the `remote_addr` If it's an internal IP that user is coming from, redirect to internal link, if not internal IP redirect to external link. There is a small example [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#rewritecond)